# Formatting conditional structures in Pine Script?

Tags: newline, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'd like to have my code a little bit cleaner, so I wish to use a new line for each one of my conditions concurring to create a certain "group" of strategy.entry conditions. Easier to show than to tell. See the following:

one of my strategy.entry condition "groups":

```
ent_FishLow() =>
    inDateRange == true
    mmfast>mmslow
    rsi<35
    fish1<-3
```

The actual entry process, which evaluates if this or another group is verified:

```
if ent_RSILow() or ent_FishLow() or ent_TrendUP_FishLow() or...
    strategy.entry()
```

BUT... it doesnt work unless I format all that stuff in one line, annding the operator AND between conditions with the result of being less readable and user friendly, like that:

```
ent_FishLow() =>
    inDateRange == true and mmfast>mmslow and rsi<35 and fish1<-3
```

Is there anything I can do to put those conds in different lines?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are missing the `and` and `or` operators in the following function:

```
ent_FishLow() =>
    inDateRange == true
    mmfast>mmslow
    rsi<35
    fish1<-3
```

You another problem is, when you want to have multi line statements, your next line should begin with one or several (**different from multiple of 4**) spaces.

The following example works without any problems.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script")

r = ta.rsi(close, 14)
a = ta.atr(10)

_l() =>
    r > 40 and
      a > 4  // Note the indentation

plot(_l() ? 1 : 0)
```

Comment: Aww ok... I was using the default TAB (4 spaces indentation) and it kept giving me errors. A single space is fine, amazing, thank you!